# 男子より女子の方がロマンチックよ。

Tags: grammar, translation, comparative-constructions

The sentence

> 男子より女子の方がロマンチックよ。

apparently translates to

> Girls are more romantic than boys.

But I'm having trouble parsing this. First off, where is the sentence's verb? Second, the literal translation seems to be something like:

> ((Young men than) young women)'s direction romantic

Is this correct? If so, it doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

Comment: AよりB方がC is a set phrase. B is more C than A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

より is used to compare things, 方 can have differents meanings depending the context (as usual in japanese), here it's used to make comparaison, opposed as より.

So 男子より -> Compared to (young)men, 女子のほうがロマンチックよlady are (more) romantic!

> where is the sentence's verb?

After ロマンチック, the copula です(だ) is omitted in this sentance but it's your "verb" "to be" (kind of)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I thought only sentences ending in i-adjs can omit verbs (since the copula is inside i-adjs, implicitly).  I guess this is wrong!

Comment: ^ @George, よ can function as a copula. It sounds soft/feminine. eg 「もうすぐ春よ。」(noun+よ) 「〇〇が好きよ。」(na-adj.+よ) See naruto's answer here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61185/9831 (`よ and ね work without だ...`) Also, 明鏡国語辞典 says: "よ〘終助詞〙❷ 活用語の終止形や**体言、形容動詞語幹**、終助詞「わ」「の」など**に付く**。 ... **体言や形容動詞に直接「よ」を付ける**とき、上昇調のイントネーションを伴うと**やわらかい言い方**になる（「あしたは休みよ」）。"